# Access Pagelayout assigned for a profile for a object using metadata api

Tags: apex, lightning, metadata-api

I need to access the **PageLayout NAME** assigned for logged in user for a given Object or Record Id. This details needs to be fetched in Lightning component. I think due to security restrictions, Lightning doesn't allow sending HTTP request directly to fetch pageLayout assigned for the logged in user unless we create Connected App, Auth Providers and Named Credential. So I thought of using Metadata API. Is there a way to fetch it using Metadata API? Can I get a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The API that is intended for this use case is the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm), which provides support for getting user interface presentation information like the correct layout for a given record and user.

While it's possible to do so with the Metadata API, ordinary unprivileged users can't access the Metadata API at all - it's not *easier* to authenticate for MDAPI than UI API, it's *harder*.

Even granting the appropriate permissions, it would involve quite a bit of excess complexity to retrieve the relevant `Profile`, `CustomObject`, and `PageLayout` entities, walk the XML, and generate the proper layout, and the latency of the Metadata API would make performance unacceptable.

Comment: I need to access the assigned PageLayout Name dynamically for the logged-in user for a given record id / object and record type. Rest of accessing the details of pagelayout is already completed. I don't want to hardcode the details of PageLayout name.

Comment: @NoNicknameSFDC I definitely get that, but the Metadata API is not a good solution for you.

Comment: Going thru the example here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_quick_start.htm , this works when I am building a custom UI. Even I would agree on this part. My intention is to use Lighting:EditRecordForm with fields loading automatically. Thats the intention behind. With UI API, it becomes too much of code and manual deployments in my case, which would be difficult to convince.

Comment: @NoNicknameSFDC It's hard to provide more detail without hearing more about your use case (which is information you can edit into your question). I'm not sure why you need the page layout *name* alone, or why you would opt not to use [`<lightning:recordForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation), which does a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Adding this detail to your question can help produce more valid answers.